# Was there ever an Aindra sect? Devotees of Indra who believed that only Indra and no other Deva is Brahman?

Tags: vedas, brahman, indra

Many people today are saying that Indra is the supreme Brahman. This theory is primarily advocated by people who reject the Upanishads and believe that the Rig Veda Samhita is the only true Veda.

Similar to Vaishnavas and Shaivas, was there ever an Aindra sect? Devotees of Indra who believed that only Indra and no other Deva is Brahman?

If so, who was the earliest Vedic scholar to identify as an Aindra?

**NOTE:** To clarify, I am looking for someone who is identified as an exclusive Indra-devotee, similar to vaishnavas and shaivas. Basically, someone who thinks *only* Indra is the parabrahman. I'm not looking for people who say all gods are identical or brahman or anything like that.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your earlier question? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36907/who-was-the-earliest-vedic-scholar-to-claim-that-only-indra-and-no-other-deva-is

Comment: @LazyLubber Question was sort of misleading before edits. Wanted a fresh start and more clarity.